# Efficient way to select with multiple criteria from subset on MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

From this data:

```
id   user_id  attribute 
-------------------------
0    11        blue        
1    11        red      
2    11        white         
3    11        green        

4    22        blue      
5    22        red       
6    22        grey       
7    22        black
```

Which is the most efficient way to query all users that have a **variable sized** sub-set of attributes like:

```
Querying 'blue' and 'red' should return:

user_id  
--------
11
22 

Querying 'blue' and 'grey' should return:

user_id  
--------
22
```

Comment: Do you have a table containing all the possible attributes?

Comment: @Frazz No I don't. These can be any word.

Comment: Uhm... I don't think you can build a query that can handle a "variable" sized set of attributes. The answer given by Gordon is good, but notice that the structure of the query changes if you have 2, 3 or N attributes. You cannot use parameters, so you'd have to build the SQL dinamically.

Comment: check the @Gordon Linoff, answer, do you want like that or not

Comment: @Frazz building the query dynamically is not a problem here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach using `group by` and `having`:

```
select user_id
from table t
group by user_id
having sum(attribute = 'blue') > 0 and
       sum(attribute = 'red') > 0;
```

If you want to put things in a list, you can alternatively use:

```
select user_id
from table t
where attribute in ('blue', 'red')
group by user_id
having count(distinct attribute) = 2;
```

However, the `2` has to correspond to the size of the list.